How do I detect if a key has been pressed?
I have a function which takes around 10 seconds to run. I want it to run over and over again until I press a certain key, then finish up the function.
I could use the python keyboard module to detect if a key is pressed, but if I press a key while the function is running, it won't detect that. Is there a function that put the keys pressed in a queue, which I could unload every time the function ends?
I've tried this code:
import pygame
import time
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.init()
def f():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('done')
running = True
while running:
    f()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                running = False

but that only works when q is pressed in the pygame window

You didn't say whether you were using windows or linux.  On windows, you can use kbhit
import msvcrt
import time

print("hit any key to continue")
while not msvcrt.kbhit():
    time.sleep(1.0)

print("hitted")

